# Installing Opencv make error

Tags: raspbian, opencv

When I try to install opencv-3.0-alpha with python 2.7 to Raspberry pi 2. I got an error.

> [ 24%] Building CXX object
>   modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/matmul.cpp.o [ 24%]
>   Building CXX object
>   modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/opencl_kernels_core.cpp.o
>   Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_core.so /usr/bin/ld:
>   ../../../3rdparty/ippicv/unpack/ippicv_lnx/lib/ia32/libippicv.a(ippinit.o):
>   Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 3)
>   ../../../3rdparty/ippicv/unpack/ippicv_lnx/lib/ia32/libippicv.a: error
>   adding symbols: File in wrong format collect2: error: ld returned 1
>   exit status modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/build.make:1213:
>   recipe for target 'lib/libopencv_core.so.3.0.0' failed make[2]: ***
>   [lib/libopencv_core.so.3.0.0] Error 1 CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1392:
>   recipe for target 'modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all' failed
>   make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2
>   Makefile:137: recipe for target 'all' failed make: *** [all] Error 2

What should i do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Bit of googling leads me to believe it might be related to compiling 32bit version of OpenCV on a 64 bit OS where it tries to link against a 64 bit library OR vice versa.

see this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15782420/libtool-links-with-32-bit-version-of-libstdc-so-on-a-64-bit-target-platform-wh) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27176297/1635109) has a solution that might work for you

Answer (score 1):

Got this error when build static opencv, solve this by disabling `IPP` in cmake.

```
WITH_IPP=OFF
```